# Is there a plot hole or deleted scene in the film?

Tags: plot-explanation, hitch

Why would Will Smith's character *Hitch* be seeking forgiveness at the end of the movie when in-fact, Eva Mendes is the one who should apologize to him?

This bugged me for a very long time, because it does not make any common sense, unless there is a deleted scene, or something above my level of understanding.

At some point in the movie, Eva Mendes finds out that one of her friends was raped by someone who used the services of Will Smith. She then suspects that he is some sort of a pimp, and tries to set him up.

When she confronts him about it, we clearly see that he is hurt and was mistakenly, and wrongfully accused. He storms out of the scene angry. But then comes back to Eva Mendes while she is packing her stuff, and tries to convince her to stay with him.

We see no evidence of regret by Eva Mendes for her wrong assumption, and even worse, while he is "apologizing" and trying to make her stay, she makes him (and us) think that the other man with her is her new boyfriend.

Has no one else asked the same question?

Comment: Uh, couldn't the answer just be **"women!"**?

Comment: I'm voting to close as opinion based. This isn't a plot hole, it's really just a (very mannerly!) rant in disguise (i.e. off-topic). We're supposed to be led down this path where we believe that Hitch needed to change and that last scene was evidence of his change. Whether she made false assumptions etc isn't really relevant to *his character's change*.

Comment: @AndrewMartin Thanks, but my question was: Is there a plot hole or a deleted scene. Closing the question since there is no plot hole contradicts the purpose of having this site

Comment: @Ahmad: I had missed the Deleted scene part, as I was reading the body of the text. Ignoring that for a moment though, closing the question certainly wouldn't contradict the purpose of the site. Any questions that are totally unanswerable as they are purely opinionated are closeable as being off-topic. Your deleted scene question is enough to keep it open, but without that it's not a great question. You haven't really found a plot hole, you've found someone's behaviour differs from what you expect - if we allowed *every* type of question like this there'd be no end to them.

Comment: @AndrewMartin Well, then that is the answer. I don't see how this is different than many other plot explanation questions where people simply haven't understood the course of the plot or the characters' actions. Is the answer obvious? Maybe. Is it a plot hole? Not really in a movie like that. But is it any more opinion-based than many other questions/answers? I don't think so. Voting to be left open!

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: *"Is the answer obvious? Maybe. Is it a plot hole? Not really in a movie like that."* - that's generally enough for me to vote to close! It doesn't really matter now. An answer is there which (hopefully) satisfies the OP).

Comment: Eh, sorry for stating the obvious, but there is a scene where Eva's character apologizes to Hitch, Hitch blows her off, hence the need for Hitch to apologize!

Comment: @AidanO: So what? If a character storms off on another in a film and never apologises, are we to get this type of question *every time*? It's not a plot hole, it's just life.

Comment: @AndrewMartin, you miss the point I'm trying to make, I agree with you that this can happen in real life, and probably wouldn't be a plot hole.  What i'm saying in this case is that Eva's character apologizes, so i'm not sure how there is even a suggestion of a plot hole.

Comment: @AidanO: I re\lised that after I posted it, Apologies! Totally agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Shouldn't Eva Mendes is the one apologizing to him?** (My personal interpretation)

Absolutely yes, In rational thinking, a person who made a mistake should be the one apologizing other person, but in the matters of relations, it can be tricky. Sometimes, you may have to apologize to your loved one even though it's her mistake because you're too afraid that you're gonna lose her forever. Will's character Hitch must be thinking in the same way.

Putting the relations BS aside, you mentioned when Eva was known that Will is not a bad person and was wrongly accused by her, she did not go to him and apologized. I can state few reasons.

1. She's too guilty to confront him and apologize because by the time she realized, she has already damaged his reputation.
2. Waiting for the right moment to apologize to him.

As per the last scene, you've wrongly interpreted (my assumption, no offense). Hitch is a comedy movie and the last scene they've made is supposed to be funny. Assume that, if Will straight away goes to her and apologizes to her and obviously she takes him back then kisses and so on. If that's the scene then there's no fun and surprise in that.

I believe no scenes were deleted and the writers deliberately made that scene that way for a bit of suspense and fun.

Comment: You should probably add that no deleted scene covers this (the other question from the OP). Other than that, this is spot on :)

Answer (score 5):

There is not a deleted scene, but it sounds like you did miss a crucial scene near the end. I am literally watching this movie right now, and following the scene at the speed-dating restaurant where Hitch confronts Sara and discovers that she had the wrong impression of him, there is a scene that is implied to take place about a week later. It shows Hitch on a sidewalk, returning home from a jog, and Sara is waiting for him. She apologizes to him during that scene but he is cold to her and essentially says he feels nothing for her. This is essentially him reverting to the way he had behaved before he met her, where he kept up a barrier between himself and love.

Finally, it is AFTER that scene (after Albert talks to him) that he realizes he loves Sara and leads into the finale where Hitch apologizes to her. So... he's apologizing for rejecting her apology, NOT apologizing for the prior stuff.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The question is flawed because it asks why Sara didn’t apologize; but she *did* apologize. The ending scene is Hitch regretting having not accepted her apology.